# How uncheck in change on RTC?

Tags: rtc

I've accidentally checked in some changes in a change set and I don't want to deliver them.

How do you move a change from a pending changeset to unresolved changes in RTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual option is "[**discard**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtc/v2r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_discarding_change_set.html)", but that would *remove* the changes (it actually remains in the repository, but is not listed in any folder, so it feels like your changes just vanished).

What I usually do is:

- backup first those files (somewhere outside the sandbox or local workspace)
- discard
- copy back the files in the sandbox
- refresh the sandbox.

The help page mentions another tip:

> To make it easier to retrieve a discarded change set that does not exist in any other stream or workspace, you can associate it with a work item before you discard it and then accept it from the work item later.

Comment: Actually it's what I do, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way. Something like just to move the change.

Comment: @rvazquezglez an easier way is what the work item  tip is for, mentioned at the end of my answer.

Comment: I will use it. Thank you.